# Value is overriding with last if always

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to use multiple if-then-else blocks but it gave "else without if" problem then I changed it into the following code but it's giving always last if value, it does not exit at the first "safe" value.

```
Range("AD" & i - 1).Select
Range("AD" & i - 1).Value = 0.3
If Range("AN" & i - 1) = "Safe" Then
Range("AD" & i - 1).Value = 0.3
ElseIf Range("AN" & i - 1) = "Not Safe" Then Range("AD" & i - 1).Value = 0.35
End If
If Range("AN" & i - 1) = "Safe" Then
Range("AD" & i - 1).Value = 0.35
ElseIf Range("AN" & i - 1) = "Not Safe" Then Range("AD" & i - 1).Value = 0.4
End If
If Range("AN" & i - 1) = "Safe" Then
Range("AD" & i - 1).Value = 0.4
ElseIf Range("AN" & i - 1) = "Not Safe" Then Range("AD" & i - 1).Value = 0.45
End If
If Range("AN" & i - 1) = "Safe" Then
Range("AD" & i - 1).Value = 0.45
ElseIf Range("AN" & i - 1) = "Not Safe" Then Range("AD" & i - 1).Value = 0.5
End If
```

[image]

Following code is alternative to last one

```
Range("AD" & i - 1).Value = 0.3
If Range("AN" & i - 1) = "Safe" Then
Range("AD" & i - 1).Value = 0.3
ElseIf Range("AN" & i - 1) = "Not Safe" Then Range("AD" & i - 1).Value = 0.35
ElseIf Range("AN" & i - 1) = "Safe" Then Range("AD" & i - 1).Value = 0.35
ElseIf Range("AN" & i - 1) = "Not Safe" Then Range("AD" & i - 1).Value = 0.4
ElseIf Range("AN" & i - 1) = "Safe" Then Range("AD" & i - 1).Value = 0.4
ElseIf Range("AN" & i - 1) = "Not Safe" Then Range("AD" & i - 1).Value = 0.45
ElseIf Range("AN" & i - 1) = "Safe" Then Range("AD" & i - 1).Value = 0.45
End If
```

but this is exiting after giving the value 0.35 only and not looking for the next lines

Comment: You are always checking the same conditions... whether if `Range("AN" & i - 1)` is safe or not, so the last if will be the one you will get.

Comment: Advice for good code - You can use `Range("AD" & i - 1).Value = 0.3` instead of using `.Select` and then setting the value.

Comment: @Damian okay, how to exit from if block after satisfying the first condition (Range("AN" & i - 1) = "Safe") so that next conditions do not execute.

Comment: @jamheadart thanks, i didn't notice it

Comment: Your code will always exit on the first if then @surendrachoudhary, you can get ride of all your code but the first If because it will do the same with an `Exit Sub`

Comment: @Damian Actually this "safe" cell contains a formula which changes with value 0.3, 0.35, 0.4 etc, basically I'm trying to do iteration.  so it can show "safe" for a cell with value of 0.4 and still for another cell this value can be 0.45

Comment: Then your code is not doing that... your code is checking that cell, and changing another cell depending on the Safe/Not Safe status... Maybe posting a little bit of explanation and screenshots of your desired output will help us to help you

Comment: @surendrachoudhary I see the screenshot but still need an explanation of what are you trying to accomplish here.

Comment: @Damian Added screenshot, Please see that.......As you can see in formula bar, "safe" or "not safe" status changes with value in 14th row and AD column.....its showing "not safe" for 0.3 value but it will be "safe" if enter "0.45" instead of 0.3...basically I want to iterate values with a gape of 0.05 and starting with 0.3

Comment: your goal is to turn all the rows safe?

Comment: yes,  I want to do iteration for each value and it should show safe in AN column

Comment: @surendrachoudhary `AK` and `AL` cells are formulas which depend on the `AD` value? If so, can you tell or show me the formula for these cells please?

Comment: AK=+(AB14*AC14)/((I14/100)^0.5)  ,
  AL = =+AF14^1.67/AG14^0.67  ,
  AF = +AD14*AE14  ,
  AG = +AD14+2*AE14               @Damian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your original code indented:

```
Sub Test()

    Range("AD" & i - 1).Select
    Range("AD" & i - 1).Value = 0.3

    If Range("AN" & i - 1) = "Safe" Then
        Range("AD" & i - 1).Value = 0.3
    ElseIf Range("AN" & i - 1) = "Not Safe" Then
        Range("AD" & i - 1).Value = 0.35
    End If

    If Range("AN" & i - 1) = "Safe" Then
        Range("AD" & i - 1).Value = 0.35
    ElseIf Range("AN" & i - 1) = "Not Safe" Then
        Range("AD" & i - 1).Value = 0.4
    End If

    If Range("AN" & i - 1) = "Safe" Then
        Range("AD" & i - 1).Value = 0.4
    ElseIf Range("AN" & i - 1) = "Not Safe" Then
        Range("AD" & i - 1).Value = 0.45
    End If

    If Range("AN" & i - 1) = "Safe" Then
        Range("AD" & i - 1).Value = 0.45
    ElseIf Range("AN" & i - 1) = "Not Safe" Then
        Range("AD" & i - 1).Value = 0.5
    End If

End Sub
```

This code can be converted to this one:

```
Sub Test2()

    Range("AD" & i - 1) = 0.3
    If Range("AN" & i - 1) = "Safe" Then
        Range("AD" & i - 1).Value = 0.3
        Range("AD" & i - 1).Value = 0.35
        Range("AD" & i - 1).Value = 0.4
        Range("AD" & i - 1).Value = 0.45
    ElseIf Range("AN" & i - 1) = "Not Safe" Then
        Range("AD" & i - 1).Value = 0.35
        Range("AD" & i - 1).Value = 0.4
        Range("AD" & i - 1).Value = 0.45
        Range("AD" & i - 1).Value = 0.5
    End If

End Sub
```

As you can see, you are only checking the value for `Range("AN" & i - 1)` and you are only checking if its safe or not. So what would the converted code do?
If it's safe will:

```
Range("AD" & i - 1).Value = 0.3
Range("AD" & i - 1).Value = 0.35
Range("AD" & i - 1).Value = 0.4
Range("AD" & i - 1).Value = 0.45
```

Which means the value for `Range("AD" & i - 1)` will be the last one because VBA will run line by line.

The same will happen if it's not safe.

So you need to check for different conditions, or check in different cells or give value to different cells.

Edit: As for the OP's comment and goal this should do the trick:

```
Sub Test2()

    'Here we have the values that we will input to turn the cell AN Safe
    'If needed you can change (1 to 4) to (1 to x) yo increment or decrement the values
    Dim Values(1 To 4) As Single

    'here we populate the array with the values:
    Values(1) = 0.35
    Values(2) = 0.4
    Values(3) = 0.45
    Values(4) = 0.5

    'A Range variable to loop through the cells in column AD from row 13 to the last
    Dim C As Range
    Dim i As Long
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Med Drain - 246 to 264 Km")
        For Each C In .Range("AD13", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AD").End(xlUp))
            'Here we check if AN is safe or empty to ignore the row if true
            If .Cells(C.Row, "AN") = vbNullString Or .Cells(C.Row, "AN") = "Safe" Then GoTo SkipRow
            'Now we loop through the values inside the Values array and change the AD cell value
            For i = LBound(Values) To UBound(Values)
                'Change AD Value for the first in our array
                C = Values(i)
                'Recalculate the formulas
                .Calculate
                'If AN is now Safe then we exit this inner loop
                If .Cells(C.Row, "AN") = "Safe" Then Exit For
            Next i
SkipRow:
        Next C
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: understood that mine code will give the last value only...can you suggest a code if I want to do iteration on a cell based on a different cell result.....Have you understood what I'm trying to accomplish @damian

Comment: @surendrachoudhary check my last block of code after the edit... If I understood your logic this should work.

Comment: That is weird @surendrachoudhary this code goes from AD13 to the last AD cell that there is in your sheet... maybe there is only one Not Safe? or maybe the values inserted won't turn AN to safe?

Comment: Why result cell value is showing 0.34999996, 0.40000034 instead of 0.35 and 0.40 in the cells....please help to notice the cause

Comment: @surendrachoudhary because of [this](https://www.vitoshacademy.com/excel-vba-floating-point-numbers-in-excel-not-exact/)